# AKT and chemoresistance in cancer

Tags: cancer, review

I would like to know your opinion about a paper on AKT-mediated chemoresistance and ion channels.
The idea is that the protein AKT is involved in chemoresistance by activating several downstream subcellular pathways like c-myc and p53.

Then, these two proteins may lead to the activation of ABC transporters like MDR1 and MRP5, two transporters involved in chemoresistance.

The paper has been published in arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.07427

Thanks.